# Administration views change filter on my content type fields

Tags: views, nodes, users

I'm using **Administration views** and I would like to be able to search by the **last name** field in my "Registration" content type. Currently, I can search by **first name via the 'title' field** on the content type as I replaced title field with my "first name" field. But now I would like to search on "Last Name" field.

Please provide a recommended approach to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin/structure/views/view/admin_views_node and add a filter criteria on the field "last name". While adding the field check "Expose this filter" and you will be able to search on last name

Comment: Thanks for quick response and i'm sorry i was not gd enough to describe what actually i need. Let me try again.

by following your steps i can add one more search filed on administration-views along with title, type, author etc... But i would like to search by last name from "title" filed(without adding an extra filter criteria). Currently i can search on first name as i replaced my(Registration) content type title to first name. I hope that everything is clear now .

Thanks